# Complex polynomial division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $m$ be the number of integers $n$, $1 \le n \le 2005$, such that the polynomial $x^{2n} + 1 + (x + 1)^{2n}$ is divisible by $x^2 + x + 1$. Find the remainder when $m$ is divided by 1000.

For this problem, I have thought of using binomial theorem to expand $(x+2)^{2n}$, but I still cannot find any relation between the divisor and dividend.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $w$ is a root of $x^2+x+1=0,w^2+w+1=0$

and $w^3-1=(w-1)(w^2+w+1)=0\implies w^3=1,w$  is a complex cube root of unity

Now $f(n)=w^{2n}+1+(1+w)^{2n}=w^{2n}+1+(-w^2)^{2n}$

$f(n)=w^{2n}+w^{4n}+1=w^{2n}+w^n+1$ as $w^3=1,w^{3n}=(w^3)^n=1$

Observe that if $3\nmid n,f(n)=0$